# how to rename file upload with sonata bundle

Tags: php, symfony, sonata-admin, sonata-user-bundle, sonata-media-bundle

How to rename file i download with sonata-bundle ?

the file is PDF and the name in database folder is : `/upload/media/default/0001/01/0000000013ac6bf9000000017c7d6398.pdf` 
I want my file appears like this : `/upload/media/0001/01/myfile.pdf`

thank you !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't wan't the file (type file only) to be rename during upload by sonata and keep its original name then you have to override sonata's `FileProvider` class , when you install [`Sonata's Media Bundle`](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media) its good to have a child bundle by generating its [`easy extend`](https://sonata-project.org/bundles/easy-extends) bundle by default it generates extended bundle in `src\Application` but your free to choose your own location, once you have its extended bundle that is in `src\Application\Sonata\MediaBundle` you can override the `FileProvider`'s class parameter (`sonata.media.provider.file.class`) by defining in your configuration file (yml,xml etc)

```
parameters:
    sonata.media.provider.file.class: Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\FileProvider
```

And now extend your `FileProvider` class with sonata's `FileProvider` so that other functionalities will work as it is

```
namespace Application\Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider;
//... other uses classes
use Sonata\MediaBundle\Provider\FileProvider as BaseProvider ;
class FileProvider extends BaseProvider
{

    public function __construct($name, Filesystem $filesystem, CDNInterface $cdn, GeneratorInterface $pathGenerator, ThumbnailInterface $thumbnail, array $allowedExtensions = array(), array $allowedMimeTypes = array(), MetadataBuilderInterface $metadata = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name, $filesystem, $cdn, $pathGenerator, $thumbnail);

        $this->allowedExtensions = $allowedExtensions;
        $this->allowedMimeTypes  = $allowedMimeTypes;
        $this->metadata = $metadata;
    }

    protected function generateReferenceName(MediaInterface $media)
    {
        return $media->getName();
        /** return $this->generateMediaUniqId($media).'.'.$media->getBinaryContent()->guessExtension();*/
    }

}
```

In above class sonata sets file name in `providerReference` by calling `generateReferenceName()` in this function its generates a unique name for each file using `sha1` something like `sha1($media->getName().uniqid().rand(11111, 99999))` so to have a original name for the uploaded file just return `$media->getName()` in this function and your uploaded file will have same name

Comment: If doing this I would suggest adding a timestamp or at least rand(11111, 99999) to the filename, because the file can get overwritten if another file with the same name is uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

To change the file (file type only) name before download you can follow my previous answer for overriding `FileProvider` class and then in your class  override base file provider's `getDownloadResponse()`function and define your desired name for the download file

```
public function getDownloadResponse(MediaInterface $media, $format, $mode, array $headers = array())
{

    $guesser = ExtensionGuesser::getInstance();
    $extension = $guesser->guess($media->getContentType());
    // build the default headers
    $headers = array_merge(array(
        'Content-Type'          => $media->getContentType(),
        'Content-Disposition'   => sprintf('attachment; filename="%s"', 'myfile.'.$extension),
    ), $headers);

    if (!in_array($mode, array('http', 'X-Sendfile', 'X-Accel-Redirect'))) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Invalid mode provided');
    }

    if ($mode == 'http') {
        if ($format == 'reference') {
            $file = $this->getReferenceFile($media);
        } else {
            $file = $this->getFilesystem()->get($this->generatePrivateUrl($media, $format));
        }

        return new StreamedResponse(function() use ($file) {
            echo $file->getContent();
        }, 200, $headers);
    }

    if (!$this->getFilesystem()->getAdapter() instanceof \Sonata\MediaBundle\Filesystem\Local) {
        throw new \RuntimeException('Cannot use X-Sendfile or X-Accel-Redirect with non \Sonata\MediaBundle\Filesystem\Local');
    }

    $filename = sprintf('%s/%s',
        $this->getFilesystem()->getAdapter()->getDirectory(),
        $this->generatePrivateUrl($media, $format)
    );

    return new BinaryFileResponse($filename, 200, $headers);
}
```